# Evaluating $\int \tfrac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}dx$

Tags: calculus

> answer from book $x - \ln(e^x + 1)$ $~~~$    **I get ** $- \ln \vert 1 + e^{-x} \vert + C $

$$\int  \frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}\, \mathrm{d}x $$

$$\begin{array}{l c l} 
u & = & 1 + e^{-x} &\\ 
\mathrm{d}u & = & -e^{-x}\: \mathrm{d}x 
\end{array} $$

$$-\int \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u}  $$

$$\Rightarrow -\ln \vert 1 + e^{-x} \vert + C $$

I don't think I made any mistake.  How do I get the answer in the book?

Comment: Just a quick note: it is generally frowned upon to have a post title which is only TeX.  I would suggest chang it to "Evaluating \int \frac{e^{-x}}{1 + e^{-x}}dx$ or something like that.

Comment: Especially so when the integral lacks its $dx$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just note that

$$
\ln(e^{-x} + 1) = \ln(e^{-x}(1 + e^x)) = -x + \ln(1 + e^x).
$$

Also, note that you can drop the absolute values as $e^x$ (and hence $e^{-x}$) is always positive.

Answer (score 1):

Take $u=1+e^{-x}$. Then $-\text{du}=e^{-x}\text{dx}.$ Therefore, $$\int \frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}\text{dx}=-\int\frac{1}{u}\text{du}=-\ln|u|+C=-\ln|1+e^{-x}|+C=-\ln(1+e^{-x})+C,$$ with the last equality following from the fact that $|1+e^{-x}|=1+e^{-x}$ since $1+e^{-x}>0.$